# Why is the output of a fork() in a particular order?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, printf, fork

I am doing some Operating System 101 homework and digging through some C code.

I am new to C and Linux so i have this maybe unusual question. I had to examine a C program to figure out, how many processes it starts. So I read a lot and tinkered with the original code to answer the all the questions.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
   printf("Start ID %d\n\n", getpid());

   printf("1.fork() from ");   
   printf("ID: %d\n", getpid());
   fflush(stdout);
   fork();

   printf("2.fork() from ");
   printf("ID: %d my parent is ID %d\n", getpid(), getppid());   
   fflush(stdout);
   fork();

   printf("3.fork() from ");
   printf("ID: %d my parent is ID %d\n", getpid(), getppid());  
   fflush(stdout);
   fork();

   sleep(2);   
   printf("%d finished. Good Night!\n", getpid());
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There is one thing I don't understand. Why are the outputs of `printf()` before the forks in this order:

```
1.fork() from ID: 3124
2.fork() from ID: 3124 my parent is ID 2215
3.fork() from ID: 3124 my parent is ID 2215
3.fork() from ID: 3126 my parent is ID 3124
2.fork() from ID: 3125 my parent is ID 3124
3.fork() from ID: 3125 my parent is ID 3124
3.fork() from ID: 3129 my parent is ID 3125
```

I would expect

```
1.fork() from ID: 3124
2.fork() from ID: 3124 my parent is ID 2215
3.fork() from ID: 3124 my parent is ID 2215
2.fork() from ID: 3125 my parent is ID 3124
3.fork() from ID: 3125 my parent is ID 3124
3.fork() from ID: 3126 my parent is ID 3124 
3.fork() from ID: 3125 my parent is ID 3124
3.fork() from ID: 3129 my parent is ID 3125
```

because PID 3124 starts PID 3125 with the first `fork()`, both another two child processes with the second and so on. Does the CPU not execute the processes in the order the have been created? This is not part of my homework, but I am still curious about it.

Comment: Threre is no logic here which process executes first.

Comment: Not true, there is a flow. There are multiple possible outputs, but some things are guaranteed to happen before others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really determine which process will be executed first. Like **HackerBoss** stated the `printf` can also influence this order.

Imagine your main program pid (`3124`) generates child `3125`. After generating the child the following instruction needs to be invoked by both father and child:

```
printf("2.fork() from ");
```

At this point there are two directions:

1. Fater `3124` invokes the `printf`
2. Child `3125` invokes the `printf`

Since the `printf` requires `I/O scheduling` it depends on the `process priority` and on the `resource state` (there could be another process already already using the resource, making it a `busy resource`).

So it looks like in your program the father `3124` gets access to the resource first and continues executing up to the next fork, where child `3126` gets generated.

At this point there is the same question: in which direction shall I go? The next instruction is:

```
printf("3.fork() from ");
```

Directions are:

1. Fater `3124` invokes the `printf`
2. Child `3126` invokes the `printf`

From your program it looks like the first process to invoke it is child `3126`.

So actually the `printf` does not assure you the process generation order. Since it is transparent how the `I/O scheduling` works, a better way would be to store a value in a specific address different for each process, by wrapping the `fork` in a `if` statement:

```
pid=fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    //child process
} else {
    //father process
}
```

This way you can have a better idea on what the `process scheduler` is doing, since it could actually be the `process scheduler` that starts a child before another, there are a lot of scheduling algorithms. At this point the `OS` you are running also influences the process execution order, depending on the used algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `printf` statements can vary from run to run, since one forked process may finish faster than another. In these cases, it is helpful to draw a fork tree diagram to determine all of the possible cases. In your case, you can only guarantee that the first print statement will print first, the second print statement will print before the third print statement within the same fork, and the second print statement will print before the third print statement in the second forked child. This gives several possible outputs. Technically, it is possible that one process would not finish in 2 seconds and would print its output after one of the finish statements, although this is unlikely.

P.S. It is good practice to wrap `fork` in an `if` to check for system errors, but it will usually work.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! It makes sense now. btw: This code was provided by my teacher. I added only the lines with getpid() outputs.

Comment: Okay, well it is easier to explain without the extra checks. This is why we had a `Fork` wrapper in one of my CS classes which did that check internally.